# Fetching Multiple Images uploaded in a single Post from Fire-base Storage Reference

Tags: android

I am uploading multiple images per a single post then saving the images in a folder in storage reference.
When displaying a single post, I need to be displaying the multiple images stored in the folder via a recyclerview.

I have tried using Database reference to fetch using valueEventListener to no avail.
I have also tried initiating Listener for the storage reference to no avail.

I tried this:

```
 reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(attachedpics);
        reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

            }
        });
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(attachedpics);
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                imageadapater pojo = postSnapshot.getValue(imageadapater.class);
                list.add(pojo);
            }
            adapter = new adapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I need to fetch all the images in a certain folder then display them in a recyclerview. Then click on another post and display the images in the attached folder

Comment: do you get any errors? if so you need to add it to the question too

Comment: No errors displayed

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I used document reference to set the name of each storage folder with an array of all the images urls. I then used the for method to reach and display every URL in my view pager.